# trying to load .csv file into std::vector<struct>

Tags: c++, function, csv, vector, struct

I'm trying to write a function to load a `.csv` file into a `vector<item>`:

```
std::vector<Item> LoadDataFromFileStruct(std::string filePath)
{
    
    std::fstream fileCon;
    fileCon.open(filePath);
    std::vector<Item> items{};
    
    while (fileCon.peek() != EOF) {
        Item item{};
        while (fileCon.peek() != '\n')
        {
            std::getline(fileCon, item.marca, ',');
            std::getline(fileCon, item.modelo, ',');
            std::getline(fileCon, item.cv, ',');
            std::getline(fileCon, item.m2h, ',');
            std::getline(fileCon, item.preço, '\n');

        }
        items.push_back(item);
    }
    fileCon.close();

    return items;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when the compiler gets to line 6 (`std::vector<Item> items{};`), it skips to the `return items;` line, I checked this using the Visual Studio debug tool.

The program compiles.

Also, I realize that it will get stuck in the inner `while` loop.

I'm very new to programming, so it might be something simple.

I have also written the following code in order to load data from the `.csv` file into a `vector<vector<string>>`, which works without this problem.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> LoadDataFromFile(std::string filePath)
{
    //Vars
    std::ifstream fileCon;
    fileCon.open(filePath);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> loadedData;
    //Iterator
    if (!fileCon.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open files";
        return std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>{};
    }
    while (fileCon.peek() != EOF) {
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::string celStr{ 0 };
        while (fileCon.peek()!='\n')
        {
            std::getline(fileCon, celStr,',');
            row.push_back(celStr);
            if (celStr.back()=='\n')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        loadedData.push_back(row);
    }
    fileCon.close();
    return loadedData;
}
```

I don't really know what to try next. I suspect that using a `vector` of struct objects was a bad idea.

Comment: The best next step would be to fix [the known antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) and see if things improve. (Side note: Looking for `\n` is just as wrong as looking for `EOF`.)

Comment: `fileCon.peek()` -- I bet there is no need to be using this function.  What makes the file you are processing special in that you need to be using obscure functions like this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the file isnt special, I used that function because I saw it in a totorial, I previusely thaught of writing in the 1st line of the csv documento the number of lines to read, but this way looked better.

Comment: @PedroRocha -- *I used that function because I saw it in a totorial* -- Well, I worked 13 years at a job and had to handle all sorts of csv files with different delimiters (not just commas), etc., and not once in all of that time `peek()` needed to be used.  Maybe you should post exactly one or two lines in the file you are trying to process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem I'm having is that when the compiler gets to line 6 (`std::vector<Item> items{};`), it skips to the `return items;` line, I checked this using the Visual Studio debug tool.

The only way I can see that happening is if `fileCon.peek()` is returning `EOF` immediately, ie if the file was not opened successfully, which you are not checking for in the 1st example (but you are in the 2nd example).

That being said, there is no good reason to use `peek()` at all in either example.  Both can be made simpler by reading the file line-by-line using `std::getline()` and parsing each line with `std::istringstream`, eg:

```
std::vector<Item> LoadDataFromFileStruct(std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream fileCon(filePath);
    std::vector<Item> items;
    
    if (!fileCon.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
        return items;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std:getline(fileCon, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Item item;

        std::getline(iss, item.marca, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.modelo, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.cv, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.m2h, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.preço);

        items.push_back(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> LoadDataFromFile(std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream fileCon(filePath);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> loadedData;

    if (!fileCon.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
        return loadedData;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(fileCon, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::string celStr;

        while (std::getline(iss, celStr, ',')) {
            row.push_back(celStr);
        }

        loadedData.push_back(row);
    }

    return loadedData;
}
```

In the 1st example, I would even suggest taking it a step further by defining an `operator>>` for `Item`, and then you can simply use `while (fileCon >> item)` instead, eg:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &input, Item &item)
{
    std::string line;
    if (std:getline(input, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        std::getline(iss, item.marca, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.modelo, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.cv, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.m2h, ',');
        std::getline(iss, item.preço);

        if (iss.fail()) {
            input.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }

    return input;
}

std::vector<Item> LoadDataFromFileStruct(std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream fileCon(filePath);
    std::vector<Item> items;
    
    if (!fileCon.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
        return items;
    }

    Item item;
    while (fileCon >> item) {
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Or, even construct the returned `vector` using a `std::istream_iterator`, eg:

```
std::vector<Item> LoadDataFromFileStruct(std::string filePath)
{
    std::ifstream fileCon(filePath);
    
    if (!fileCon.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
        return std::vector<Item>{};
    }

    return std::vector<Item>{
        std::istream_iterator<Item>(fileCon),
        std::istream_iterator<Item>{}
    };

    // or simply:
    // return {std::istream_iterator<Item>(fileCon), {}};
}
```

Comment: Also an option in that last block: [`return {std::istream_iterator<Item>(fileCon), {}};`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3217f2d9ca814346)